# MATLAB Code for solving desired 'n' number of simultaneous equations of the type Ax = b

Tags: matlab, matrix, simultaneous, equations, triangular

**Problem in MATLAB Code for solving desired 'n' number of simultaneous equations of the type Ax = b provided that the solving involves the method of upper triangular matrix and the values of A and b are evolved into Aprime and bprime along with the x values.**

The problem is to write a code that can solve "n" number of simultaneous equation of the type Ax = b using upper triangulation matrix. The values of A and b are given as matrix in the command window. The code should return Aprime, bprime and x values as the answer when the program is run successfully. The code should also give the output as "Error, Matrix dimensions doesn't match" (or whatever !) for certain equations ! The code works fine except it shows an error along with the above given Error message.

The code I used is as follows,

```
function [x, Aprime, bprime]=solved(A,b)
    n = size(A);
    % Assign the size of A to n.
    if (n(1)~= n(2)) || (det(A) == 0)
        % Checking through the determinant method for dimension error.
        disp('ERROR!! Matrix dimensions should agree.')
    else
        for j=1 %:n-1
            % Fix the first value of j to 1.
            if A(j,j)==0
                u=A(j,:);
                A(j,:)=A(j+1,:);
                A(j+1,:)=u;
                %using u as a temperary value "u", to save the row,to swap the positions of two rows.
                v=b(j);
                b(j)=b(j+1);
                b(j+1)=v;
                %using u as a temperary variable "v", to save the row,to interchange the positions of two rows in b matrix.
            end

            for i=j+1:n
                if A(i,j)~=0
                    %If the first number of the particular row  be zero.
                    b(i)=b(j)+(b(i)*(-A(j,j)/A(i,j)));
                    A(i,:) = A(j,:)+(A(i,:)*(-A(j,j)/A(i,j)));
                end
                %After this 'for'loop, the matrix becomes a upper triangle matrix.
            end

            Aprime=A;
            bprime=b;
            x=A\b;
            % Using this command the values of x,y,z can be found.
        end
    end
end
```

Please provide the suitable correction....

Results as obtained on the command window,

> > A = [1 1 0;2 1 1;1 2 3]

A =

```
 1     1     0
 2     1     1
 1     2     3
```

> > b= [3;7;14]

b =

```
 3
 7
14
```

> > [x, Aprime, bprime] = solved(A, b)

x =

```
 1
 2
 3
```

Aprime =

```
1.0000    1.0000         0
     0    0.5000   -0.5000
     0   -1.0000   -3.0000
```

bprime =

```
3.0000
```

-0.5000
  -11.0000

The second type is,

> > A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]

A =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
```

> > b = [7;8;9;10]

b =

```
 7
 8
 9
10
```

> > [x, Aprime, bprime] = solved(A, b)
> >     ERROR!! Matrix dimensions should agree.
> >     Error in solved (line 2)
> >     n = size(A);
> >     Output argument "x" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
> >     "C:\Users\Hari\Documents\solved.m>solved".

Comment: Can you fix the formatting you your question? It is very hard to read at the moment.

Comment: If I understand your question all you have to do is set x, Aprime, and bprime to something (like x=[];) where you are displaying the error

Comment: I dont understand what formatting you mean ! The question is to solve simultaneous equations of the type Ax=b using upper triangular matrix !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `disp`, use the function `error` to communicate an error.  That will tell MATLAB not to try to continue with execution after the error.  Plus, the style will match builtin MATLAB errors.

Comment: using "error" instead of "disp" returns the same error...is the logic correct with the program ?

Comment: No, when I replace `disp('ERROR!! Matrix dimensions should agree.')` with `error('Matrix dimensions should agree.')`, my output now just prints the error message and line number.  When you ask "is the logic correct", what do mean?  Your question says "The code works fine, except for the error message".  Is there something else that you want help with?  If so, please edit your question to clearly state your question.

Comment: yes, it works !! I didn't save the last time when I run it ! now it's fine ! about the logic, i meant if the program is suitable for solving n no. of simultaneous eqns of the type Ax=b using upper triangular matrix !

Comment: Is there a possibility that this program can be made simpler with 20-23 lines of coding ? without using lot of "if" statement ?

Comment: That's a different question!  The whole problem is strange.  Is this homework?  If so, you probably shouldn't use \ at all, which will work just as well right at the beginning.  Instead, use back-substitution to solve the equation.  If it's not, skip the upper-triangular part entirely, and your whole function will be `x=A\b;`